# How to get Python to run a submodule from that submodule's path for relative paths?

Tags: python, directory, path

I have a project that's a big complicated in file directory.

```
    project/
        scripts/
            scriptA.py
            ...
        data/
            A.csv
            ...
```

The files in `scripts\` will modify things in `data\`. The actual structure is a more nested and involved. This currently works fine since I'm testing each file separately, but I would like to include a `run.py` in the root directory which would run through all the relevant scripts.

However, `scriptA.py` and so forth are all written with relative paths like `../data/A.csv` which means  `run.py` won't run. What would be the best way to go about this? I've looked into Python's `__file__` but I'm still not sure how to use it for my purposes.

Comment: If in root, ../../data/abc.csv should work or add script/ to your path `import sys.path.insert(0,'/path/to/script')`

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel would I have to do this for every script? Do I do it all at once in the beginning or, include that, run the corresponding script and repeat?

Comment: It depends on your use cases. If it is something you would like to have in all scripts at root, then I would do abit differently. I would create a `__init__.py` file st root and import all necessary paths. This means I don’t have to change my run.py as all paths a loaded in the initialization.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Python 3, I'd do it like this:

```py
# This is scriptA.py
from pathlib import Path

script_a = Path(__file__)
scripts_dir = script_a.parent
project_dir = scripts_dir.parent
data_dir = project_dir / 'data'
a_csv = data_dir / 'A.csv'

with a_csv.open():
    # Some work on the file
```

You probably wouldn't actually break it out into a bunch of different variables like that, I just did so for illustration.  Checkout the [pathlib docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/pathlib.html) for more info.